# Why are multiple tkinter canvas images only showing once?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I have a loop to make multiple canvas images on a canvas.
But when I run my code, only one image appears.
(Just assume the window is already set up as `root` and `PIL` is imported)

```py
 1 x,y = 0
 2 tiles = []
 3 tilesize = 32
 4 gridwidth = 10
 5 gridheight = 10
 3 canvas=Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, bg="#800000")
 4 for i in tiles:
 5         image = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open("tile.png").resize((tilesize, tilesize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS))
 6         tiles.append(canvas.create_image(x*tilesize, y*tilesize, image=image, anchor=NW))
 7         x+=1
 8         if x%gridwidth == 0:
 9                 y+=1
10                 x=0
11         if y == gridheight+1:
12                 # Do some error handling stuff
```

If after this if I add `print(tiles)` I see a list of incrementing values, as it should be. eg:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5...98, 99, 100]
```

If I run this:

```
13 test=[]
14 for i in tiles:
15         test.append(canvas.coords(i))
16 print(test)
```

I see that all the tiles have different coords, but all they show up as is one image.
My expected output is that they show up as a grid, but that does not happen.
Why is this happening, and are there any solutions?
And no, the `grid` function does not help for my current context.

Comment: You need to save the instances of `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)` in a list as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use same variable `image` for all the images created in the for loop, only the last image is referenced by `image` and the previous images will be garbage collected.

Use a list to store the instances of images:

```py
...
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
...
imagelist = []
for i in range(gridwidth*gridheight):
    y, x = divmod(i, gridwidth)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("tile.png").resize((tilesize, tilesize), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    tiles.append(canvas.create_image(x*tilesize, y*tilesize, image=image, anchor=NW))
    imagelist.append(image) # save the image reference
...
```